# How can I make the Firefox Web Console automatically scroll as new output is logged?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools, firefox-developer-edition

I am using Firefox (Developer Edition) as my primary debugging environment for web-development. Is there any way to make the Web Console automatically scroll to keep up with new output as it is logged?

I am using Webpack with hot-module-reloading that the Web Console quickly fills up with messages. If it could automatically scroll, I would not need to move the mouse across two wide-screen monitors just to scroll down ever time I save code or HTML changes -- eyes move quicker than the mouse.

Comment: It already does this, as far as I can tell, as long as you're at the bottom of the console log.

Comment: That's what I thought. However, I have produced a scenario where that doesn't happen and the bug occurrs with 100% reproducability on my system so I thought that the feature was simply not working.

Comment: I guess it's a genuine bug. I'm currently in the process of submitting a bug report.

Comment: Does appear to be a genuine bug and it's probably this one: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1533667

Comment: Looks like this keeps regressing - see comments here: https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/how-to-make-the-console-automatically-scroll/36677/18
 It *should* be fixed in build 101